# no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'gnu_cxx::normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int>>&&'. I'm unable to find a way to get my code working

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, iterator, c++17

I am trying to carry out a binary search to find the index of a specific element within the vector. I tried getting the first and last element and passing them to the variable high and low. I am getting some sort of conversion error. The error is below inside the BinarySearchVector funtion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

    int limit=10;
    vector <int> elements; 
    void AddValueToVector(){
        cout<<"Hello World:"<<endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            int a;
            cin>>a;
            elements.push_back(a);
        }   
        
    }
    void printContents(){
        cout<<"Vector elements:"<<endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
        {
            cout<<elements[j]<<endl;
        }   
    }

    int binarySearchVector(vector<int>&elements,int searchval){
        sort(elements.begin(),elements.end());

        auto low= elements.begin();
        auto high= elements.end();
         while (low <= high) {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

            if (elements[mid] == searchval)
            return mid;

            if (elements[mid] < searchval)
            low = mid + 1;

            else
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        return -1;     
    }

    void search(){
        int searchval;
        cout<<"Enter value to search:"<<endl;
        cin>>searchval;
        int result= binarySearchVector(elements,searchval);
        if (result==-1)
        {
            cout<<"Not Found"<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"Element is found at index"<<result<<endl;
        }
        
    }
 
int main()
{
    AddValueToVector();
    printContents();
    search();
    return 0;
}
```

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `binarySearchVector` function is supposed to return the index of the found element (not an iterator) you should probably not use `begin()` and `end()` (that return iterators, not indices).

Example:

```cpp
int binarySearchVector(std::vector<int>& elements, int searchval) {
    std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end());

    int low = 0;                    // index of first element
    int high = elements.size() - 1; // index of last element
    
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

        if (elements[mid] < searchval)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (elements[mid] > searchval)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked for me. It's my first time working with Vectors, do you know of any useful resources?

Comment: @AckeemMclennon You are welcome. I think SO is a good resource. It has plenty of good examples if you search for c++ vector.

Answer (score 0):

To use the binary search method you need to sort the vector.

The variables `low` and `high` are iterators

```
    auto low= elements.begin();
    auto high= elements.end();
```

There is no implicit conversion an iterator to an object of the type `int` that you are trying to do

```
     while (low <= high) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        //...
```

You need to write at least

```
        auto mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
```

or

```
        auto mid = std::next( low,  std::distance( low, high ) / 2 );
```

Moreover the condition in the loop

```
     while (low <= high) {
```

is incorrect for an empty sub-range because in this case when `low` is equal to `high` the body of the loop will get the control and the operations with iterators within the body of the loop will invoke undefined behavior. You need to write

```
     while (low < high) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
int mid = *low + (*high - *low) / 2;
```

an iterator is effectively a pointer to the element. If you want the element itself you need to dereference it